# Two representations of $\text{M}_n(k)$ of same dimension are isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $k$ be a field. Is it true or not that any two representations of the algebra $\text{M}_n(k)$ of the same (finite) dimension over $k$ are isomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. That algebra is semisimple and has exactly one isomorphism class of simple modules.